# Get list of previous months from start of the year

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, php-carbon

I'm trying to get a list of previous months using `Carbon`.

Expected result:

```
January, February, March, April
```

What I did so far:

```
$now = Carbon::now();
$startMonth = $now->startOfMonth()->subMonth($now->month);
$currentMonth = $now->startOfMonth();
$diff = $currentMonth->diffInMonths($startMonth);
```

I've used `Carbon::now()` to get the first month of the year, then I tried to calculate the difference between the dates but I got `0`.

Also I canno find any method that returns a list of months as the expected output.

Comment: Why not just do `->startOfYear()` to get the first month of the year?

Comment: *"`Carbon::now()` to get the first month of the year"* - `Carbon::now()` will get Today's date, not the first month of the year... `Carbon::now()->startOfYear()` or `(new Carbon\Carbon())->startOfYear()` will get the first Month of the year (via the first Day of the year)...

Comment: When you modify `$now`, it completely modifies it, so when you set $startMonth, it's also setting `$now`. You need to use `copy()` if you want the original to stay the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not a simple `while` loop?

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

$previousMonths = [];

$currentDate = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth();
while ($currentDate->year == Carbon::now()->year) {
  $previousMonths[] = $currentDate->format('F');
  $currentDate->subMonth();
}
```

`$previousMonths` would now be:

```php
[
  "April",
  "March",
  "February",
  "January",
]
```

Edit

---

If you need them in the opposite order, then:

```
$previousMonths = array_reverse($previousMonths);
```

Then `$previousMonths` will be:

```
[
  "January",
  "February",
  "March",
  "April",
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the original variable to December 1st of the previous year, since you keep modifying the original instead of copying it. Instead, create two variables off of `now()`, then you can use that to create a CarbonPeriod to iterate through.

```
$firstOfYear = Carbon::now()->firstOfYear();
$firstOfLastMonth = Carbon::now()->firstOfMonth()->subMonth(); // If you want to include the current month, drop ->subMonth()
$period = CarbonPeriod::create($firstOfYear, '1 month', $firstOfLastMonth);
foreach($period as $p) echo $p->format('F')."\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using PHP range:

```
$now = Carbon::now();
$months = collect( range(1, $now->month) )->map( function($month) use ($now) {
    return Carbon::createFromDate($now->year, $month)->format('F');
})->toArray();
```

This should return a collection of months (array if toArray() is used) from January until the current month (similar to the expected result)